# Getting value from clean URL into a webform hidden field in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I am including a webform that a user will fill out on a job listing page if they are interested in the job. The job listing page itself is created from a custom module as the result of a job search and I am including the webform like so:

```
render(node_view(node_load(363), 'full', NULL));
```

where 363 is the webform id. So I'm trying to figure out how I can pass at least the job number into the webform. I know I can edit the webform to include a hidden field where I can get values from the URL like %get[key] but I am using clean URL's so I do not have a specific key in the URL like www.example.com/jobs?job_number=1234 where I can grab "job_number". My actual URL looks like this: http://www.example.com/job-board/view/41904 so I need to grab 41904 in my webform. How can I accomplish this? Can I use a special token in my webform hidden field or is there a way in my custom module to somehow pass the job number to the webform when I go to display it on the job detail page?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured this one out. So it looks like right before I call my webform, I can actually set a $_GET parameter and it will pass to the webform. So I did this in my custom module:

```
// send job_number to webform via $_GET
$_GET['job_number'] = $job_number;
render(node_view(node_load(363), 'full', NULL));
```

Now in my webform, I added a hidden form field that has %get[job_number] as the default value and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the arguments by using arg();

try

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(arg());
echo "</pre>";
```

In you case you can get it by `echo arg(2);`

Comment: Actually so that is a good way to access an argument from the clean URL in code somewhere, but that doesn't help me here because I need to be able to access it from the webform hidden field. Just for kicks I tried %arg[2] as the default value and it didnt work, so I would still need to pass the job number in the $_GET variable.

Comment: I just realized I wasn't very clear in my original post. I actually already have a handle on the job_number in my module where I am rendering the webform. I do not need to get it from the URL. I was just trying to figure out how I would pass that job number to the webform, because as far as I could tell the only token I could use in the webform default value field was a %get[key] and I am using clean URLs. %arg[2] would have been nice, but that didn't work. So for now the, below method I used seems to work. Thanks for informing me about arg(2) though. I didn't know you could do that!